# PHP, substr symbols from the end

Tags: php, symbols, substr

There are number '2352362361 ', as it is separated by spaces from the end of 3 characters?
The output should obtain '2 352 362 361 '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that number as a string :

```
$str = '2352362361 ';
```

You can first convert that string to an integer, using [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) :

```
$int = intval($str);
```

And, then, use [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) on that integer :

```
echo number_format($int, 0, '.', ' ');
```

And you get :

```
2 352 362 361
```

*(If the space at the end was intentional, you can add it back if necessary)*

And `number_format` will also work even if you pass it the string without converting it to an integer first :

```
$str = '2352362361 ';
echo number_format($str, 0, '.', ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

number_format($num, 0, '.', ' ');

Answer (score 1):

Try [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
number_format('2352362361',0,'',' ')
```

note that argument 3 is empty, where argument 4 is a space